# Does Selenium Webdriver bypass browser default pop-up blockers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, popup-blocker

So my team ran into a strange situation today, when run manually one of our tests fail due to firefox's pop up blocker ending up blocking the window that is supposed to open. But when we run our automation Webdriver ignores the pop-up blocker and the window opens successfully.

So the question is does Webdriver have something built in that ignores all default browser pop-up blockers? And can I disable it.